# a problem in geometric probability

Tags: probability

Inside a square of side $2$ units , five points are marked at random. What is the probability that there are at least two points such that the distance between them is at most $\sqrt2$ units?

---

Totally stuck on it. How can I solve this.

Comment: Exactly $\sqrt{2}$? If so, it will be 0, since the probability that any 2 points are a fixed distance apart is 0.

Comment: sorry for my mistake.now I corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to ask what is the probability that at least one pair of points is less than $\sqrt 2$ apart.  If so, you could think about the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 2):

$p=0$ because the furthest separation between 5 points in a square is with one at each corner and one in the middle, but by Pythagoras theorem the distance between the corner and the middle is $\sqrt2$. Not a formal proof I grant you but the logic is infallible.

Comment: @fabee that's no problem, the center of a square of side length $l$ is ${l^{2}}\over2$

Answer (score 1):

1. Divide the square into 4 squares of side length 1.In at least one square there are two or more points. All points in the same square have  distance less than 2^0.5. So the answer is 1